# B+ tree iterative

Tags: c++

I have implemented a b+ tree in c++ but i have a problem to iterate and print all value but not recursiv this the implentation of the node

```
class Node {
bool IS_LEAF;
int *key, size;
Node **ptr;
};
```

I hope someone can help me with this or give idea how can iterate

Comment: Please pay close attention to the tags you select for your questions, so you don't spam irrelevant tags. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please add a [mre] and all errors you get to clarify what "a problem" is.